# jQuery not working well on firefox and not working at all in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, firefox, safari

i am using jQuery.unique() to get rid of the double values inside a Javascript array. In Chrome it works nice and the length of the array goes from 60 to 29, in Firefox it does something strange as it goes from 60 to 43 and in safari it doesn't work at all, any hint?
here are the imports I use:

```
  <title>APS</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link href="../css/jquery-ui-1.10.4.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/reset.css">
  <link href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp/css/shift.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp/css/bootstrap.css">
  <script src="../js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="../js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.js"></script>
  <script src = "../js/search.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/styles.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.2.18.min.js"></script>

</head>
```

and the js:

```
$(function() {
        Parse.initialize("T1S9kR0SEibdUjxpyOzaYccrGMVJmwOoaqclBDDO", "IiGFcSejnTIvfhTIEumgElGx9vru9MbdMora8SSZ");
    var query = new Parse.Query("pruebas");
    query.find({
            success: function(objects) {
        var centros=["VILLAVICIOSA", "EL VALLE", "PALOMERA", "ENCINAR", "SAN MATEO"];
        var tipos = ["Esporadico", "Semanal", "Esperando"];
        var nombres=[];
        var pruebas = ["Nacho", "Nacho ", "NACHO", "Nacho"];
        console.log(pruebas.length+pruebas);
        console.log(jQuery.unique(pruebas).length+jQuery.unique(pruebas));
        var emails=[];
        var dias = [];//"Lunes", "Martes", "Miercoles", "Jueves", "Viernes", "Sabado", "Domingo"];
        var dnis=[];
        var i =0;
        objects.forEach(function(obj) {
                nombres[i] = obj.attributes.NOMBRE;
                emails[i] = obj.attributes.MAIL;
                dnis[i] = obj.attributes.DNI;
                dias[i] = obj.attributes.DIA;
                i++;
        });
        console.log("longitud de dias antes: "+dias.length);
        console.log("longitud de dias despues: "+jQuery.unique(dias).length);
        $('#nombres').focus();
        $( "#nombres" ).autocomplete({
            select: function( event, ui ) {console.log(ui.item.value);$('#emails').val('');$('#dnis').val('');
            $('#dias').val('');$('#centros').val('');$('#tipos').val('');},
            source: nombres,
            autoFocus: true
        });
        $( "#dias" ).autocomplete({
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                console.log(ui.item.value);
                console.log(
                objects.filter(function( obj ) {
                return obj.attributes.DIA == ui.item.value;
                }));
                $('#emails').val('');$('#dnis').val('');
            $('#nombres').val('');},
            source: jQuery.unique( dias ),
            autoFocus: true
        });
        $( "#emails" ).autocomplete({
            select: function( event, ui ) {console.log(ui.item.value);$('#centros').val('');$('#nombres').val('');$('#dnis').val('');
        $('#dias').val('');$('#tipos').val('');},
            source: emails,
            autoFocus: true
        });
        $( "#dnis" ).autocomplete({
            select: function( event, ui ) {console.log(ui.item.value);$('#centros').val('');$('#emails').val('');$('#nombres').val('');
        $('#dias').val('');$('#tipos').val('');},
            source: dnis,
            autoFocus: true
        });
        $( "#centros" ).autocomplete({
            select: function( event, ui ) {console.log(ui.item.value);$('#emails').val('');$('#nombres').val('');},
            source: centros,
            autoFocus: true
        });
        $( "#tipos" ).autocomplete({
            select: function( event, ui ) {console.log(ui.item.value);$('#emails').val('');$('#nombres').val('');},
            source: tipos,
            autoFocus: true
        });
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log("An error occured :(");
            }

        });

        $('#borrarBusq').click(function(){
            $('#nombres').val('');
            $('#emails').val('');
            $('#dnis').val('');
            $('#dias').val('');
            $('#tipos').val('');
            $('#centros').val('');
        });
    });
```

Thanks!!

Comment: can you remove all the irrelevant code from the question, and just show the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jQuery.unique](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.unique/) works on DOM elements only:

> Description: Sorts an array of DOM elements, in place, with the duplicates removed. Note that this only works on arrays of DOM elements, not strings or numbers.

You need to implement your own routine or use something like [lodash](http://lodash.com) or [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/)

Comment: Thanks! I ended up implementing my own function to do it but really wanted to know what happened. Any idea why it works differently in different browsers? I mean the query file is the same for all and the JavaScript also I don't quite see why I get different results, thanks for the response!

Comment: No, I don't really know why, I'm not into jQuery implementation, but here is [the function](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/90b43de21296cf59af7dd37c49c1a9a4f8483f68/src/sizzle/dist/sizzle.js#L895) that is actually called. Good starting point if you want to understand why. It actually relies on some environment detection, so it may behave differently on purpose, but it was never meant to work on plain (non-DOM) collections.